# Folium marker icon not showing correctly

Tags: python, folium

I'm trying to plot a folium marker on a folium map but the icon is not showing correctly.
I am expecting a green teardrop with white info-sign in the middle. But the info-sign is not displaying. I tried this on multiple platforms (Colab, VS code, Jupyter Notebook) but still facing same issue.

I tried it on another machine and it works. Anyone encountered this before? Is this because of ram limitation on my machine that I'm not aware of?

[image]

```
Chicago = folium.Map(location=[41.878876, -87.635918], zoom_start=10)
folium.Marker([41.878876, -87.635918], 
              popup="Aka Willis Tower", 
              tooltip='Sears Tower', 
              icon=folium.Icon(color='green',icon_color='white',icon='info-sign')
             ).add_to(Chicago)
Chicago
```

Comment: My environment was displayed correctly. (folium 0.12.1) It also displays correctly in Colab. (folium 0.8.3) I can't help you there, but here is a report of the execution.

Comment: thanks for checking. Yea, it still remains a mystery. Probably just have to make do with running it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
icon = folium.Icon(color=color_lines[gdf_estaciones.LINEA[i][1]],icon='info',prefix= 'fa',icon_color='white'),
```

Add " prefix= 'fa' "

[map with info icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDseb.png)